# CNN - Is this a Toeplitz Matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network

I have been reading through Chapter 9 of [www.deeplearningbbook.org](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html), where convolutional networks are being described.

The following image represents the output of a 2D convolution, without kernel flipping.

[image]

The book goes on to describe this matrix as a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) where,

> for univariate discrete convolution, each row of the matrix is constrained to be
>   equal to the row above shifted by one element.

I fully understand this statement since `w`, `x`, `y` and `z` are constants in their respective columns with shifting elements.

However, there is no mention of **diagonal-constants** which are a key feature of such matrices. As per Wikipedia (link above) and several other sources:

> a Toeplitz matrix or diagonal-constant matrix, named after Otto Toeplitz, is a matrix in which each descending diagonal from left to right is constant.

Going back to the image above, does this mean that, for instance, `aw == cx == gy`? How can this be ensured when all elements are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, be assured that the **kernel matrix** (the 2x2 matrix in the figure) in CNN is not constrained to have its diagonal filled with a unique value, and is thus **not a Toeplitz matrix.**

In [www.deeplearningbook.org](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html),  we can read:

> "Discrete convolution can be viewed as multiplication by a matrix, but the matrix has several entries constrained to be equal to other entries"

This means that the **global** operation of passing a kernel on the input data of a CNN could be expressed as the multiplication of this input data by a matrix. i.e. by a large and sparse Toeplitz matrix.

Authors mention the illustrative simple case of *univariate discrete convolution*. In univariate discrete convolution, we would be applying a 1-D kernel matrix of length $m$ on 1-D input data of length $n$. Let us take n=10 and m=3.
Doing the convolution could be done by multiplying the input vector data by a n*n matrix, whose diagonal would be composed of the 3 weights of the kernel, shifted of one column to the right at each new row.